# Is there a Docker-ce version compatible for Ubuntu 16.04(i386 arch)? I find nothing on Web, only amd64, arm64 and other archs etc

Tags: docker

According to the official tutorial, it says "Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/, choose your Ubuntu version, browse to pool/stable/ and choose amd64, armhf, ppc64el, or s390x. Download the .deb file for the Docker version you want to install.". I did check that url, no deb for i386.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/install/#supported-platforms lists the supported architectures and 32-bit x86 Linux isn't one of them.

The desktop Docker for Mac and Docker for Windows applications only run on 64-bit x86; the Linux system component runs on 64-bit x86 (but not 32-bit), 64-bit ARM, and IBM Power (ppc64le) and Z (s390x) platforms.  Prebuilt distribution packages are only available one some of those architectures, though all of CentOS, Debian, Fedora, and Ubuntu are available for 64-bit x86 and Ubuntu packages are available for all supported architectures.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that  someone have to compile the source code if an i386 version deb file requires for ubuntu. Is that what I can conclude?

Comment: Also given that all of the distro-specific install pages specifically say you need a 64-bit distro, you might have word-size-compatibility issues.

Comment: This URL(https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) is the tutorial  I referred to. Since I run Ubuntu 16.04 in VMware which installed on a Mac Pro, 64 bit x86 version is required.